# Angular JS - Filtering based on checkbox groups (AND & OR conditions)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

I am using angularjs for one of my project. I am trying to implement a filtering functionality.

I am constructing the filter check boxes using the code below

```
<div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="incidentType in keywords.incidentType">
<label><input type="checkbox" value={{incidentType}}>{{incidentType}}</label>
</div>
```

The result is shown in image below

[image]

On checking or unchecking the check boxes, I need to create a object like below. Based on this json object I will send a request to server to fetch the matching data.

```
{
    "application": [
        "Athena",
        "EWS"
    ],
    "incidentType": [
        "Publishing Failure",
        "Security Failure"
    ]
}
```

Any idea on how can this be achieved in angularjs. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for something like this, you can use an object like what you want to send as the model, then bind it to the data in your ng-repeat. I let you check here first : http://jsfiddle.net/DotDotDot/gcEJH/
I've taken your sample code and I just added a controller with an object (`$scope.checked` ) which I use for the ng-model in each checkbox

```
$scope.checked={application:{}, incidentType:{}};
```

then, in the HTML

```
<div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="incidentType in keywords.incidentType">
<label><input type="checkbox" ng-model='checked.incidentType[incidentType]' ng-true-    value='{{incidentType}}'>{{incidentType}}</label>
</div>
```

The ng-model part tells angular to put the value in the incidentType part of the object, under the kay corresponding to the value. This won't give you the exact same object, but you will have something like :

```
{
"application": {
    "Athena": false,
    "EWS": true,
    "EWindows": true
},
"incidentType": {
    "Publishing Failure": true,
    "Security Failure": true
}
}
```

which is actually pretty close, and from which you can create your request (or recreate the same object you wanted easily)

Hope this helps, have fun

=)